# Is it possible to use keycloak with spring security?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

Without keycloak maven dependencies.

This is using okta and google. I wonder can I use spring security + ouath2 with keycloak?

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use withouth keycloak springboot auto-configuration

Look here: [Spring Cloud Gateway with OAuth2](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/10/09/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2-with-keycloak/)

You can see the configuration used to connect with Keycloak

Let me know if you get your answer